# Main function / program does not execute when using SDL module

Tags: c, sdl, program-entry-point

When i compile this program and execute it, nothing happens. Not even a printf statement inside the main function executes and there is no output. There is also a SDL_Delay in the program but the program terminates instantly.

Here is the code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 500;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;
SDL_Surface* image = NULL;

int init();
int loadmedia();
void close();


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("This print statement does not give any output");
    if(!init()){
        printf("FAILED TO INITIALIZE SDL");
    }
    else{
        if(!loadmedia()){
            printf("FAILED TO LOAD MEDIA");
        }
        else{
            SDL_Rect dRect;
            dRect.x = 0;
            dRect.y = 0;
            dRect.w = SCREEN_WIDTH;
            dRect.h = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
            SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screenSurface, &dRect);
        }
    }
}

int init(){
    printf("IS THE PROGRAM ENTERING THIS FUNCTION");
    int success = 1;
    if(!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)){
        printf("SDL_Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else{
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("sdlsdlsdl", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(!window){
            printf("SDL_Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
            success = 0;
        }
        else{
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        }
    }
    return success;
}

int loadmedia(){
    int success = 1;

    image = SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");
    if(!image){
        printf("SDL_Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
        success = 0;
    }

    return success;
}

void closeIt(){
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);

    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I am compiling this using a makefile which is as follows:-

```
file = SDL_file.c
output = SDL_file
compiler = gcc

INCLUDE_PATHS = -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2
LIBRARY_PATHS = -LC:\mingw_dev_lib\lib

COMPILER_FLAGS = -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

all: $(file)
    $(compiler) $(file) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(output)
```

Comment: If you want to see stdout in your console, you don't want `-Wl,-subsystem,windows`. You most certainly don't want `-w` as it suppresses all compiler warnings. To ensure stdout stream is flushed each printf should end with newline (`\n`). "There is also a SDL_Delay in the program" - I don't see any delay in given example. Build code in question without your `COMPILER_FLAGS` in makefile and edit question with output results if your question persists.

Comment: Actually, I got it to work, but didn't understand what the problem was, so yeah...